# How to paralleize search for a string in a file with a help of fork? (GNU Linux/g++)

Tags: c++, linux, file, search, parallel-processing

I got a text file  with a couple of lines and I am looking for a string in this file. I need to pass following command line parameters to the program:
- file path
- the string I am looking for
- maximum number of processes the program is allowed to "fork" in order to complete this task.

How to such a program should be constructed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of thoughts.

- You will have to open the file separately from each process, otherwise they will share a single file descriptor and thus have a shared position in the file (or not, see the comments, as this may be system specific...).
- You may not see the speed increase you are hoping for due to disk access and/or cache miss patterns.

You might be able to beat both issues by memory mapping the file (well you still risk an increased cache miss rate)...

---

How badly do you need this? It runs a real risk of being premature optimization. I would recommend against touching the problem without a compelling need. Really.

Comment: Optionally, instead of opening many file descriptors or mmapping, you can use `pread` to read from a file at many offsets concurrently.

Comment: When you call fork(), it clones the file descriptors, so that child processes will NOT share a file position with its parent, unlike threads which use the same descriptors.

Comment: @MarkR: From the fork man page on my Mac OS 10.5 system: "an lseek(2) on a descriptor in the child process can affect a subsequent read or write by the parent" (because both FILE*'s point to the same OS structure). Could this be OS dependent?

Comment: The manpage on my Debian Etch system is not specific on the matter.

Comment: Hmm ok maybe it's system specific whether seeks affect the parent's/ child's sibling's file descriptor. Closing one certainly doesn't affect another.

Answer (score 2):

Consider why you think you need to parallelize this, and if you're going to see any actual performance benefit. You're likely to be limited by disk access time, and there's overhead to forking. Your best option might be to do a standard single-threaded search (probably with a regex).

Comment: Regex searching is actually pretty slow... There are so many options, unless you use a DFA which is fast but complex. The really fast way to do it is to use the jump table trick where you read ahead by the length of the string, and backtrack by a certain amount if the character actually appears.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really think this is necessary (or is this homework ?), a (relatively high-level) way to go could be:

1. compute the size of the file to search (e.g. with fopen, fseek(file, END), fclose)
2. associate to each process two offsets in the file: a search start offset, and a search end offset:

   ```
   startIndex = indexOfProcess * fileSize / numberOfProcesses
   endIndex = (indexOfProcess + 1) * fileSize / numberOfProcesses
   ```

   You have to take into account the fact that the string to seach can span the slices for two or more processes by adding some overlap (which will be a function of the string size).
3. fork, open the file in each process (in read mode), fseek to the start index, search the string as if you had a single file of size (endIndex - startIndex), and dump the results to the screen (or, if you have more specific requirement, tell us about them).

Answer (score 1):

Either this is homework, or this is useless. The bottleneck is in disk bandwidth, not CPU power. You will only slow down by using simultaneous accesses.

Comment: It is probably homework, but if he was looking for a regex, then some of those can be computationally difficult. But he isn't looking for a regex, so I don't know why I bother mentioning it...